# Need to capture process status in log file

Tags: linux

I want to execute the below command in loop for every second(till 1 hr) and need to capture in a log file. I want to make sure timestamps in those output file

/bin/ps -eo user,pid,ppid,pcpu,tty,pmem,args

could you please help?

Comment: Do you have access to `ts` utility?

Comment: no Paulo, I don't have access to ts

Comment: Would a loop like
`for (i=0;i<3600;i++) ; do /bin/ps -eo user,pid,ppid,pcpu,tty,pmem,args | sed "s/^/$i /" ; sleep 1 ;done > output.log`
work for you? Does it matter about the small time slippage?

Comment: Thanks a lot. It worked

Answer (score 0):

Many ways to go about this. Here’s one assuming bash shell is available – since you didn’t state a preference:

```
timeout 1h bash -c 'while sleep 1 ; do date "+%F %T" ; /bin/ps -eo user,pid,ppid,pcpu,tty,pmem,args ; done' > yourfile.log
```

Comment: Thanks bxm. It says timeout command not found